# Asynchronous functions in constructor

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017, koa2

I'm trying to export a class with an asynchronous call in the constructor:

`my.js`:

```
module.exports = class My extends Emitter {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.db = Object.create(db)
    this.db.init(cfg)
  }
}
```

`db.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  async init (cfg) {
    nano = await auth(cfg.user, cfg.pass)
    db = nano.use(cfg.db)
  },
  async get (id) {
    ...
  }
```

After `let my = new My()`, my.db is still empty. How do I wait for init() to be completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like

```
module.exports = class My extends Emitter {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.db = Object.create(db)
    this.waitForMe = this.db.init(cfg)
  }
}
let my = new My();
```

Knowing that async/await is just sugar for Promises, you can then wait like:

```
my.waitForMe.then(function() {
});
```